# Grouped Sum of a scores in a JSON object array based on SectionID in it

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I've a JSON object array like this

```
var scores= [{sectionid:1,sectiontitle:'Section1',score:5},
{sectionid:1,sectiontitle:'Section1',score:15},
{sectionid:1,sectiontitle:'Section1',score:7},
{sectionid:1,sectiontitle:'Section1',score:4},
{sectionid:2,sectiontitle:'Section2',score:5},
{sectionid:2,sectiontitle:'Section2',score:45},
{sectionid:2,sectiontitle:'Section2',score:13},
{sectionid:3,sectiontitle:'Section3',score:6},
{sectionid:3,sectiontitle:'Section3',score:23},
{sectionid:3,sectiontitle:'Section3',score:9},
{sectionid:3,sectiontitle:'Section3',score:12},
{sectionid:3,sectiontitle:'Section3',score:55},
{sectionid:4,sectiontitle:'Section4',score:4},
{sectionid:4,sectiontitle:'Section4',score:35}];
```

But I need to get group these JSON object array to another variable with **grouped sum of scores** in it.

So the resulting variable should be something like this

```
var result=[{sectionid:1,sectiontitle:'Section1',score:26},
{sectionid:2,sectiontitle:'Section2',score:63},
{sectionid:3,sectiontitle:'Section3',score:105},
{sectionid:4,sectiontitle:'Section4',score:39}];
```

I tried traversing the scores variable using each function. But that found to be complicated. How can we make it possible with a best and quick way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.forEach` and sectionId as an unique key to build a new array. I also used `indexMap` for fast index lookup:

```
var indexMap = {};
var result = [];
scores.forEach(function (item) {
    var index = indexMap[item.sectionid];
    if (typeof index !== 'undefined') {
        result[index].score += item.score;
    } else {
        indexMap[item.sectionid] = result.push(item) - 1;
    }
});
console.log(result);
```

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/7a6u38hd/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var ct = {}; 
for(var i=0;i<scores.length;i++) { 
    var tp= scores[i];
    var x = ct[tp.sectionid];
    if(x) {
        x = tp;
        x.score = x.score + tp.score;
    } else {
        x = tp;
    }
}
```